# Sign in with redirect using Google Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

As i see google sign in can rather create a user or sign in it so in my case i need to add a document to firestore db then redirect to "/setup-profile" when the user signs up or just redirect to "/" in case user signs in and already has the document.

Hook to get current user:

```
export const useGetCurrentUser = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<CurrentUser | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        setCurrentUser(snapshot.data() as CurrentUser);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return { currentUser, loading };
};
```

Google auth:

```
  const { currentUser } = useGetCurrentUser();
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleAuthWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRedirectResult(auth).then((result) => {
      const user = result.user;
      if (user.uid !== currentUser?.uid) {
        setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
          uid: user.uid,
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
        });
        router.push("/setup-profile");
      } else {
        router.push("/");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

The problem is that currentUser.uid is undefined in the second code. Any suggestions?